# Can I adjust when Trello due date colors change?

Tags: trello

Currently due dates turn yellow the day before, and red the day of.
Can I change this so that they turn yellow, say, a week before, and red a few days before? A day is often very short notice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, according to their card guide on [Due Dates](https://trello.com/guide):

> You can set a date and time for when a card is "due". A badge with the
>   due date will appear on cards. A yellow badge means it's within 24
>   hours of being due A red badge means it's past due.

I would suggest emailing their support team to suggest a feature.

Comment: Good idea,will do.